# Magento 2 : Product grid on front-end

Tags: magento2, product-grid

How can I show product grid on the front-end? I want a product grid to be shown on the customer front-end panel. So customers will be able to select products from the grid on my account section.

Comment: Did you completed the task?

Comment: @Mehdi Did you find the solution to this?